# Spring application freezes at the moment of launch

Tags: java, spring

I am trying to run a fairly large project (300 classes) on a local host. The maven assembly is successful, however, when trying to run using run configuration, only the welcome inscription Spring is displayed. What could be the problem?

My application properties:

```
spring.session.store-type=jdbc
spring.session.jdbc.initialize-schema=always

spring.servlet.multipart.max-file-size=16MB
spring.servlet.multipart.max-request-size=16MB

springdoc.api-docs.enabled=true

server.compression.enabled=true
# opt in to content types
server.compression.mime-types=application/json,application/xml,text/html,text/xml,text/plain,application/javascript,text/css
# not worth the CPU cycles at some point, probably
server.compression.min-response-size=4096
```

[My run configuration](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Cdo9x.png)
[My run logs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/whFqA.png)

I tried to wait and changed the logging levels in application.properties, but it didn't help.

Comment: Take a thread dump.

Comment: Not much to say for now, do as tgdavies proposed. I'll refer to https://www.baeldung.com/java-thread-dump for a guide on capturing thread dumps.